# Como personalizar barra de rolagem em div?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Tenho um menu que usa offcanvas do Bootstrap porém queria estilizar a barra de rolagem dele no estilo do chat do Facebook.

Comment: ja deu uma olhada na documentação? http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/progress_bars.html tem uns exemplos la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que personalizar o scroll não é algo que está na especificação, então não é uma necessidade que os navegadores implementem esse recurso. Alguns incluem essa característica e permite que o scroll seja customizado, repito: Alguns.

No mais, o que você precisa fazer é um scroll com CSS e Javascript. Essa é a única maneira de ter uma funcionalidade *cross browser*, é por isso que existem vários plugins que tratam desse recurso.

#### [**Custom  Scrollbar**](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<!-- dependência do JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus facilisis risus at orci fringilla, et egestas turpis hendrerit. Nulla vel leo urna. Donec blandit fermentum orci in imperdiet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec sed elit mi. Nunc eu nulla nulla.
  </p>
</div>
```

---

#### [**Nice Scroll**:](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').niceScroll();
});
```

```css
div {     
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<!-- dependência o JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.0/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus facilisis risus at orci fringilla, et egestas turpis hendrerit. Nulla vel leo urna. Donec blandit fermentum orci in imperdiet. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec sed elit mi. Nunc eu nulla nulla.
  </p>
</div>
```

Além da aparência acima é possível customizá-lo, por isso *linkei* os projetos para você ler a documentação de como fazer isso. Se nenhum dos dois atender suas necessidades, saiba que existem vários outros.

Answer (score 0):

A sua pergunta está bem genérica, pois não trás um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Então, supondo que você queira saber quais elementos (no caso, pseudo-elementos) você deve estilizar, eles são

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       
::-webkit-resizer
```

Que eu sei, só os browsers que tem o webkit por trás vão te possibilitar fazer essa estilização. No [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) tem um artigo sobre isso (que foi de onde eu tirei os elementos). [Essa discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div) no SO Gringo trás consigo todos os pormenores de se fazer essa estilização cross-browser.

Comment: Mas para que seja especifico apenas para um div como que posso fazer?